# How to properly add a JS library to a Faveod project?

Tags: code-generation

I am trying to add a `jQuery Select2` formatter to a field and it doesn't work, but it the console I have the error `TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function` and the network tab tells me that the requests to get the files `select2.min.js` and `select2.css` failed with a 404.

Do you know what could be the problem? Is my project wrongly configured?

Answer (score 3):

Faveod has its own "bower/yarn-like" management.
To add a JS lib, just use the Designer.
To do the maintenance, go into the generated app.

Designer:

1. you have to define the JS libs in the "JS frameworks" panel

App:

1. app: admin panel then "Js dependencies"
2. (optional) use the buttons to show outdated libs
3. on the lib you want to update, "get info"
4. (if needed) download it to make it available
5. (if needed) choose the version you want to use (updates the symlink)

Now reload your JSes and you're ready to go :)

Answer (score 2):

The path configured in this JS framework is incorrect : it is "/javascripts/dist/..." but should be "/javascripts/**select2**/dist/...".

Comment: I edited it but the request still fails. It's looking for it at `/javascripts/select2/select2.min.js`